Wordpress multisite block recovery works with superadmin but not other users
I am working on a wordpress multisite project.
I could not post screenshot but Html is showing on frontend (div id has html char i think). Code change is an option if creating new accordion (prob is with accordion plugin) is an option but this is the last resort.
When I perform block recovery using superadmin then block recovers and broken html is fixed but when I perform block recovery using any other user (roles such as administrator) the issue occurs again.
What could be the issue and how to fix it. What changes of capabilities are there between admininstrator role and superadmin. What can I do to fix this?
For reference -

This type of html is coming in frontend. With superadmin block recovery it gets fixed but with any other user issue reoccurs and doesnt get fixed with block recovery.
